# installation of android app on the bases of IMEI number

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to install android app on limited mobile phones on the bases of their IMEI number.
I have saved all devices IMEI numbers in server database.
When user wants to install app through web service IMEI number will be verified. web service returns true and false. IF response is true then installation should continue other wise no intallation. Is it possible ???as i can get IMEI number of device easily

Comment: Yes that is possible if you have another app already installed on that device that does the imei send to the webservice, then the download -if approved- and the install.

Comment: But what is the problem that every body can install it? Just check imei at every start of your app.

Comment: this app is for limited number of employes and devices from company so..

Comment: Yes that i understood of course. But you did not understand me. So please reread my comment. What does it matter that it is installed but cannot be used? People will soon remove it.

Comment: got your point but highlevel managment want this restriction

Comment: Then please react to my other comment and that of dragon born.

Answer (score 1):

i am afraid its not possible you need to execute the code that does the verification... solution to this problem can be ... you have a application the does the verification if the phone is authorized the you can download the actual application and then ask the user to install that application you want